# Is Maude Ivory Katniss' grandmother?

Tags: the-hunger-games, ballad-of-songbirds-and-snakes

Close to the end of *The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes*, Lucy Gray sings "The Hanging Tree" and, immediately afterwards, she is told to never sing this song again, for it brings up to many "touchy subjects", but Maude Ivory liked it.

Personally, I think either Coryo killed Lucy Gray or she became Coin.

Could Maude Ivory be Katniss' grandma, or great-grandma? Because only the covey knew about the song, and Maude Ivory remembers every song she ever heard.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell - some say Maude Ivory is Katniss's grandmother and some say Lucy Gray is Katniss's grandmother. It WOULD make more sense to say Maude Ivory because she lives in District 12, where Katniss's father lives. Furthermore, at the end of *Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes*, Snow makes an attempt to shoot Lucy Gray.

> He thought he could hear someone moving off to his right, retreating to the lake. He started running toward the sound and then stopped abruptly.  Sure enough,  having heard him,  she was flying through the underbrush, realizing what he had realized, no longer caring if he heard her. He estimated her to be about ten yards away, lifted the rifle to his shoulder, and released a spray of bullets in her direction. - **Coriolanaus Snow**

Afterward though, Lucy Gray does sing hinting that she is alive at that time. Still, it's very unclear if she is alive or dead (or up until this point, where the deciding factor comes into play).

> Her voice surprised him, lifting suddenly and sweetly into the air.
> Are you, are you / coming to the tree? / Wear a necklace of rope, side by side with me. / Strange things did happen here / no stranger would it be / if we met up at midnight in the hanging tree - **Lucy Gray Baird**

In Collin's story, there is a repeated phrase that mockingjays sing and the show is over. After Lucy Gray is finished singing, the mockingjays sing too, hinting at her death. Every time the mockingjays mimic a voice or sing, it usually follows an execution. Due to this signal, it would be safe to assume that Lucy Gray is dead like the others who the mockingjays have imitated.

> "Well, you know what they say. The show’s not over until the Mockingjay sings.”
>
> “The mockingjay? Really, I think you’re just making these things up."
>
> “Not that one. A mockingjay’s a bona fide bird.”
>
> “And it sings in your show?”
>
> “Not my show, sweetheart. Yours. The Capitol’s anyway.
>
> This must be what she’d meant. The Capitol’s show was the hanging. The mockingjay some sort of bona fide bird. Not a jabberjay. Different somehow. - **Coriolanus Snow**

Comment: His mindset also points to his 'executing' her.